# What is size for the sizeof operator in c?

Tags: c, sizeof

In recent I was attend one Interview on "SureSoft Technology"...... In that interview, they ask one question lik "What is size for the sizeof operator in c? "

If any one Know answer Share with me?

Comment: I don't understand the question, it is not grammatical. What do you mean by the expression "size for X"?

Comment: It would be appreciated if you marked an answer as accepted when it has answered your question :) You can do this by clicking the green checkmark next to the question.

Comment: @Skurmedel +1 for that. Man, you surely know how to squeeze up-votes! (:

Comment: @Poni: Haha... yeah, I'm milking that cow dry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator itself has no size. Its result will generally* turn into a constant value at compile time.

As for the value it returns, that would be the size, in bytes, of the argument. The type of the result is `size_t` (defined in `<stdlib.h>`) (§6.5.3.4.4)

* - with the notable exception of dynamically-sized automatic arrays.

Comment: I think the question was "what's the type of `(sizeof(x))` expression?"

Comment: To clarify, it is not defined as the size in bytes, although it happens to be in most implementations. sizeof(char) is always 1, even if a char is 4 bytes.

Comment: It _is_ defined as the size in bytes, because a `char` _is_ one byte. The key is that a byte may be more than eight bits (but not less).

Comment: "The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type." (§6.5.3.4.2)

Comment: @Richard, to be precise, it is not defined as the size in _octets_.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find the answers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/size_t): the result of sizeof is of type size_t, and:

> "The actual type of size_t is platform-dependent; a common mistake is to assume size_t is the same as unsigned int, which can lead to programming errors when moving from 32 to 64-bit architecture, for example.
>   According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), size_t is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bits."

Answer (score 1):

The type size_t defined in stddef.h.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - it's the size in bytes of the given data structure that you pass to sizeof.

For example:

```
sizeof(char) // one bytes
sizeof(int) // four bytes
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually it is the number of char sized units in a type. sizeof(char) is 1. It may or may not be 1 byte.

Comment: @Richard, the C standard defines a byte to be a unit of storage large enough to hold any character in the basic charset of the execution environment (§3.6.1, §3.7.1), with the restriction that it is _at least_ eight bits (§5.2.4.2.1). A conforming implementation may pack _more_ than eight bits into a char. This would still be one _byte_, but it would not be one _octet_. Of course, most systems in use today use eight-bit bytes, but a strict reading of the standard does not require that.

Comment: @bdonlan: and this isn't just academic, nor is it about ancient 9bit mainframes. There are modern C implementations in use with larger `char`, for example some DSPs only have 16bit or 32bit addressing. Non-Posix, of course.

Comment: @bdonlan: how would one determine the number of bits per byte during compiletime?

Comment: `CHAR_BIT`, in `<limits.h>` will give you the number of bits per byte at compile time. `unsigned char` is guarenteed to be a simple binary layout of these bits. Note, however, that there is **no** guarentee that the number of bits in, say, an int is `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` - there may be padding, checksum, trap bits, sign bits, and/or other implementation defined stuff lurking in there.

Comment: It is very unfortunate that the standard chose to define a byte that way, because, for most of the rest of the world, a byte is 8 bits. This makes a statement like sizeof(char) == 1 byte true, but very easy to misunderstand without a careful reading of the standard.

Comment: @Richard - I feel your sorrow, don't think about it too much, there are better issues to think of (:

Comment: @Richard: the C language was there first. The near-ubiquity of 8 bit bytes came *after* C had settled on a terminology, which is why internet RFCs say "octet" when they mean that rather than (ab)using the word "byte" the way most of the world does. By the time C89 was published they *could* as a precaution have removed all uses of the word "byte" from the standard except perhaps for a single non-normative footnote somewhere. This would have led to unfortunate phrases like "multi-char character", though.